# How recognise the developer mode in Visual Studio?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2017

I'd like to be able to recognise the developer mode in Visual Studio with JavaScript. For example:

```
function choice(res,req) {
   if (developerMode) {
      console.log("developer mode");
      readFile("data.json"); //Fictitious function
   else (!developerMode) {
      console.log("no developer mode");
      exec("./writefile"); //Fictitious shell script
   }
}
```

Has someone an idea to recognise "developerMode" ?

Comment: I think you need to use razor code embedded with your javascript

Comment: @ScottSelby How do you know that Razor is used in this project?

Comment: @mason I can embed Razor if it's necessary.

Comment: I think I am unclear if you are trying to detect if Visual Studios is running in debug mode , or if the browser has the developer tools open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I find a solution. I work with Node.js. I use the global variable NODE_ENV and I define him as NODE_ENV = 'development'. Therefore, I just test if I am in development with the comparaison NODE_ENV === 'development'. And I can change this variable when I deploy my server like that :
    NODE_ENV='prod' node server.js

Answer (score -2):

You can write to the `console` whether you are in dev. mode or not. If you are not, the messages will just go unseen.

Comment: OP is asking to detect the state with visual studio is in when running javascript... not about not writing to the console....

Comment: @epascarello {sigh} Yes, but I took the liberty of reading what the OP is doing with the code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I would execute a shell script when I don't in developer mode and just read a file when I am in developer mode.